# How to get parameter after "/" in URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, post, parameters, web

I need to let my users type anything at the end of my url, like this:

http://mysite.com/?somethingorother

or

http://mysite.com/somethingorother

And then I would like to get that last bit that they added to the end of the url like so:

```
$var = $_POST[''];
```

But I'm not sure how to go about this, and I can't find anything, because I'm not quite sure how to search for it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider using $_GET.

Comment: Okay, but how exactly would I accomplish this, when I don't know what the user has entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With http://mysite.com/?somethingorother you can use:

```
substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],2);
```

Comment: +1 - I will mark as answer when it lets me. Thanks for your help! Btw: I had to change it from 2, to 11 ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your second example you'd need to use url rewriting (search `mod_rewrite`) anyway. If there is a `?` you can just

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {   echo "$key: $value"; }
```